# Unable to connect to Firebird server from ADO.net

Tags: c#, ado.net, firebird

I recently downloaded the new Firebird 4 server and installed it.  It's running as a service on my Windows 10 box.  I'm able to connect to it just fine with the FB Maestro IDE, but when I try to connect to it from some ADO.NET code, I get an error.  Upon calling `await connection.OpenAsync` (where `connection` is a `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection` instance):

> FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException: 'Error occurred during login, please check server firebird.log for details'

Looking at the server log, I see the following two errors, repeated various times:

> DESKTOP-NAME  Thu Jun 24 15:14:32 2021    Authentication error    No
> matching plugins on server
>
> DESKTOP-NAME  Thu Jun 24 15:14:35 2021    INET/inet_error: read errno
> = 10054, client host = DESKTOP-NAME, address = 127.0.0.1/54653, user = Mason

I have no idea what this means, and some basic searching fails to turn up anything useful.  Anyone know what I need to do to resolve this?

In case it's relevant, my connection string looks like this:

> User=SYSDBA;Password=[my password];Database=[db name];DataSource=localhost;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=UTF8;

Once again, I know the server is working correctly because I can connect to it with FB Maestro.  The problem is clearly in my .NET code somewhere.  I just have no idea where!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver you use doesn't support srp256 and Firebird 4 server by default doesn't support anything else. You must edit firebird.conf changing AuthServer parameter to include srp plugin at least. Don't forget to restart the Firebird server afterward.